# Firebase Database query for http trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to query my firebase realtime database for the list of User objects. I have a *favourites* field  and in it I'm storing a list of id's of favourited users. How would I go about writing a http endpoint with cloud functions so that it returns a json list of User objects corresponding to these ids in database?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events for how to write a HTTP function, and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data to see how to read from the Firebase Database using the Admin SDK (which is available in your Cloud Functions for Firebase). If you're stuck while implementing this, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your development environment for FCF by following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). Once you've initialized your project, write a function inside functions/index.js like this one:

```
exports.getFavouriteUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  var favouriteUsers = admin.database.ref('users/favourites').val();

  res.status(200).send(favouriteUsers);

});
```

Finally deploy and you'll be able to make requests to the endpoint shown in the console.

Look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) documentation for HTTP triggers